# Uncomfortable Discussions Around Guests

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayera, abraham

Why doesn't Avraham wait until escorting the angelic "men" out of the tent before having the conversation with Sarah about "laughing" - the pesukim ([Bereishis 18:15-16](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.18.14-15?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) follow one after the other.

> וַתְּכַחֵשׁ שָׂרָה לֵאמֹר לֹא צָחַקְתִּי כִּי יָרֵאָה וַיֹּאמֶר לֹא
>   כִּי צָחָקְתְּ׃
>
> Sarah lied, saying, “I did not laugh,” for she was frightened. But He
>   replied, “You did laugh.”
>
> וַיָּקֻמוּ מִשָּׁם הָאֲנָשִׁים וַיַּשְׁקִפוּ עַל־פְּנֵי סְדֹם
>   וְאַבְרָהָם הֹלֵךְ עִמָּם לְשַׁלְּחָם׃
>
> The men set out from there and looked down toward Sodom, Abraham
>   walking with them to see them off.

Comment: "You did laugh" .. isn't that Hashem speaking to her?

Comment: Is it possible the tent was large enough this did not happen in front of the guests or that they were talking quietly enough their guests could be assumed to not have heard them?

Comment: 1. אין מוקדם ומאוחר בתורה? 2. כל מחלוקת שהיא לשם שמים סופה להתקיים?

Comment: To build on what @Dude wrote, there were clearly parts of the tent where Sarah was left with privacy (as seen by the angels asking where she was). Why not just assume that when Avraham and Sarah were talking in a private location where they wouldn't be overheard?

Comment: That's exactly my comment

Comment: @DavidKenner - not so clear - some say it was A.A. - https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.18.15?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en

Comment: @DavidKenner Ramban understands it was Avraham